# fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(15, 3),subplot_kw={'xticks': (), 'yticks': ()})の意味について

Tags: python

下記はどういう意味になりますか？
figとaxesには何が代入されているんでしょうか？

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(15, 3),
                     subplot_kw={'xticks': (), 'yticks': ()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずaxesの方から説明します。
numpy.ndarrayの中にAxesSubplotクラスのインスタンスが格納されています。
このインスタンスはサブプロットと呼ばれるもので、グラフを描画する図となるものです。
1つまたは複数のサブプロットを格納する受け皿としてnumpy.ndarrayが用意されています。

figは上記サププロットを描画するためのFigureクラスのインスタンスが格納されています。
これはフィギュアオブジェクトと呼ばれるもので、サブプロットを描画する領域となるものです。

イメージとしてはこのようになります。

```
+------------------
|fig
|+-------++-------+
||axes[0]||axes[1]|
|+-------++-------+
+------------------
```